# Как скрыть форму WinForms C# от программ стриминга/демонстрации экрана?

Tags: c#, winforms

Хочу скрыть окно своей программы от программ стриминга/демонстрации экрана, таких как Discord, OBS, Zoom и т.д.
То есть форма должна быть видна на дисплее комьютера, но не показываться при демонстрации экрана.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, гугление на инглише помогло найти ответ, вот такой код набросал, Win 10 2004 с дискордом работает.

Код:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

// namespace, class ...

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern uint SetWindowDisplayAffinity(IntPtr hwnd, uint dwAffinity);

const uint WDA_NONE = 0;
const uint WDA_MONITOR = 1;

private void hide()
{
    this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    SetWindowDisplayAffinity(this.Handle, WDA_MONITOR);
}

private void show()
{
    this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
    SetWindowDisplayAffinity(this.Handle, WDA_NONE);
}
```

На новых системах должно работать, информация с сайта документации Microsoft:

> Minimum supported client  Windows 7 [desktop apps only]

Надеюсь, кому нибудь поможет.